# How to get back the Auto archive functionality?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, autoarchive

The group policy in my company has disabled the auto archive functionality. I really need it back ( not for any nefarious purposes) simply to save me the trouble of having to do this manually.

the policy seems to allwo for the crreation of .pst. I have created a .pst file called "Archive".

But the auto archive functionality (button and optiions) is missing from outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't.

Group policies are applied every time you log on to your work PC via Active Directory, provided that the policy is registered in AD.

Even if you enable the auto-archive functionality through a registry hack, it will be disabled again next time you log on to your PC.

One way to circumvent this is to move your emails to the .pst file manually.